# Is there a name/reference for this dynamic process?

Tags: statistics, dynamical-systems, bayesian

I'm just curious about the following dynamic process:

$$
x_{t+1} = x_t\frac{y_t + \varepsilon_t}{y_t + x_t}
$$
$$
y_{t+1} = y_t + \varepsilon_t
$$

Is there a name for this? I'm trying to find references but I'm not sure what to search for.

Edit: for some additional context, this process arises from Bayesian updating of an unobserved parameter $b \sim \Gamma(\alpha_t,y_t)$, when $\varepsilon_t \sim \Gamma(a, b)$ is observed, with known $a$ and mean $x$. So $y_t$ is the scale hyperparameter of the prior for $b$ at time $t$ and $x_t$ is the posterior predictive mean of $\varepsilon_t$ given that prior: $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t\mid \alpha_t, y_t]$.

Ultimately, I'm interested in trying to estimate the $\{y_\tau\}$ when $\{\{x_\tau\}, a\}$ is observed and the $\varepsilon_t$ are observed with error, that is $\{\tilde\varepsilon_\tau\}$ are observed, where:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tilde\varepsilon_t &= \varepsilon_t + \eta_t\\
\varepsilon_t &\sim \Gamma(a,b)\\
\eta_t &\sim \text{LogNormal}(0,\sigma) \text{ or } \Gamma(a_\eta,b_\eta) \text{ or something}.
\end{aligned}
$$

So as part of this, I want to understand the properties of the dynamic process above.

Comment: What is $\epsilon$? Is it a constant or a function of time? Either way it looks like your $y'=y+\epsilon$ can be solved for $y$ in more detail (up to an initial condition).

Comment: Does this system have some special property, in the geometry of its solution set or with respect to applications? If not, it is unlikely that there is a name for it.

Comment: ϵ is a function of time, sorry. Specifically, I'm interested in treating this system as a data generating process, where the ϵ are strictly positive. Then, I believe, y goes to infinity while x converges to the mean of the ϵ. I'm interested in estimating y given observations of x and noisy observations of ϵ.

Comment: It may be a construction principle, and thus considered as implied and trivial, but it is worth to note that $z_t=\frac{y_t}{x_t}$ has the deterministic recursion $z_{t+1}=z_t+1$.

Comment: Yes, in fact (in the original Bayesian motivation I added), this $z_t$ has the interpretation of $\alpha_t/a$, the ratio of the shape parameters of the prior and the observation.